# Hide site contents link from wiki pages in Sharepoint Online

Tags: html, sharepoint

In a Sharepoint Online site I am using wiki (or traditional) pages for certains tasks and I need to hide the “Site Contents” link. This is my screenshot, and highlited, the link I need to remove:

[image: Site Content Link]

On the Internet I found [a post](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1923643-remove-site-contents-link-from-sharepoint-online) which says to manually insert a paragraph like #sideNavBox { display:none; } in the markup using the page editor.

[image: Page with manual tag]

Initially (after the click on the button OK) all seems ok, but when I publish the page the link comes back.

[Other posts](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/228987/how-to-remove-site-contents-from-the-navigation-bar-of-the-wiki-page) suggest different code but the editor seems to refuse all the styles I try to insert.

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the

```
 #sideNavBox{
  display:none!important
  }
```

into a CSS file and upload it to SharePoint, then specify this CSS file to be used by this site.
[image]

Comment: Great, thank you, it works! To enable the master page management (initially I wasn't able to see any master page voice in my Site Settings) I also found useful this post: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/89297/master-page-option-from-site-look-and-feel-is-missing